# string to time with decimal seconds

Tags: python, time, python-2.7

Say I have a string with format `HHMMSS.SS` how do I convert this to a time object?

This is how I thought you would do it:

```
import time
time.strptime(timestring, '%H%M%S')
```

However`%S` does not take take into account fractions of seconds according to the [time](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) documentation.

Comment: Check the `%f` directive in [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) docs

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You will have to use %f

```
time.strptime('26/01/12 23:50:32.123', '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Use of datetime will be right

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> a = datetime.strptime('26/01/12 23:50:32.123', '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S.%f')
>>> a.microsecond
```

Comment: Nope—`python -c "import time; print time.strptime('26/01/12 16:31:32.123', '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S.%f')"` prints `time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=26, tm_hour=16, tm_min=31, tm_sec=32, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=26, tm_isdst=-1)`—there [are no milliseconds in Python’s `struct_time`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time)

Comment: it seems you're both right: datettime DOES have a .microsecond but time doesn't. Thanks ganesh - just what I needed +1

Comment: nice, this works